# If $a$ is irrational, must $a^a$ be irrational?

Tags: nt.number-theory, irrational-numbers

It is known that $\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}}$ is irrational.  Is it true that for any irrational number $a$, $a^a$ must be irrational?

Comment: Obviously not. There is a number $a > 1$ such that $a^a = 2$. This number cannot be rational.

Comment: @Andrei Bauer my typing the proof took 7 seconds more :)

Comment: (1) this is not a race; (2) this question shouldn't have been on MO so it's better not to answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a positive number $a$ such that $a^a=2$. If $a=m/n$ with $m,n\in{\mathbb N}$ coprime, then $m^m=2^nn^m$. As $n\ge1$, we conclude that $m$ is even, sayt $m=2^kl$ with $k\ge1$ and odd $l$. So, $2^{km}l^m=2^nn^m$, implying $2^{km}=2^n$ and $km=n$. A contradiction.